# Find the second occurrence of string in a file with quoted text and return name of that String

Tags: python

I have a file abc.txt containing quoted strings.

For the following input

```
./executeSQL.sh alt_tbl.sql /scratch/app/product/fmw/obpinstall/patchStage/1000050165/files/obp/ identifyInvalidObjects.sql Current time : 15:01:34
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "echo "Curr..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "/home/alam..." - rest of line ignored.
ALTER TABLE  "FLX_PI_FIN_PROF_LIAB_DTLS" ADD ("LIAB_DTL_SL_NO" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE)
         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column
```

I want to return `alt_tbl.sql`

Comment: @AvinashRaj May be csv reader with  quotechar `csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=" ",quotechar='"')` `row=next(csvreader, None)` `print row[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will extract `alt_tbl.sql` from the file `abc.txt`:

```
with open('abc.txt') as f_input:
    text = f_input.read()
    file_name = text.split(' ', 2)[1]
    print file_name
```

Comment: This wont work for the data provided. Will fail if the second part of input is in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

With a csv reader will be more apt with a check for quotes using csv sniffer to check for multiple delimiters

```
import csv
scndval=None
li=[]
scndval=None
with open('abc.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024), delimiters=" \t")
    csvfile.seek(0)
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect,quotechar='"')
    for row in csvreader:
      li+=row
      if (li)>1:
         scndval = li[1]
         break
print scndval
```

I/P : `hello   "how are you" ?`
O/P : `how are you`